# jQuery: check input with name attribute for hasClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, input

What I'm trying to do is check if input with name attribute "Name" has a class of "input-validation-error", if so apply css to the label with for attribute of "Name".

```
if ($("input[name='Name']").hasClass("input-validation-error"))
{
    $("label[for='Name']").css("color:red");
    console.log('here');
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?
Markup:

```
<label for="Name">Name</label>
<input class="input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-required="field is required" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: you should see error thrown in console for this as a clue

Comment: code in answer given works fine with html provided. Sounds like it's a problem of when you exectute the code. Why don't you just use css for this?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
 $("label[for='Name']").css("color:red");
```

Try

```
 $("label[for='Name']").css("color","red");
```

[Read more on `.css()` here](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

---

OR

Instead of

```
 $("label[for='Name']").css("color:red");
```

Try

```
 $("label[for='Name']").attr("style","color:red");
```

---

The html provided in updated question and with above jquery modification its working see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/o7L49ots/).

As per the questioner comments below this answer , i think the questioner is adding HTML dynamically inside DOM so in that case use **event delegation** read more [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: @alex..now you completely changed your question man..hahaha..no worries there can be problem with html markup show it and please don't change the question because otherwise this answer will be completely invalid..

Comment: I disagree, if the issue isn't resolved due to only fixing one typo, the question should indeed be updated with additional information to help resolve whatever else is going on

Comment: Related: [How should I deal with lazy follow up question-comments on answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271255/how-should-i-deal-with-lazy-follow-up-question-comments-on-answers)

Comment: @Kartikeya OK...I'll rephrase, a simple syntax error. So it appears the OP issue of `not working` is still in force , there is no new question, just multiple problems

Comment: the css was my bad, but the problem is that the console message never appears, so something is wrong here `if ($("input[name='Name']").hasClass("input-validation-error"))`

Comment: @alex..see if some other css is affecting your css..just see carefully or post css also.

Comment: @charlietfl...i m not saying questioner that i will not solve the questioner trouble because i pointed out problem and posted answer ... i m just saying that after getting answer do not change the question(questioner changed .css("color:red"); with .css("color","red");) because otherwise answer will be invalid..thanks..

Comment: @alex...use .removeClass() in jquery and remove all other classes on label and then see what is happening.

Comment: the thing is it doesn't find any inputs with name attribute of "Name" with that class... the markup is from the DOM in dev tools

Comment: the markup is from a form in a partial view, div initially set to display:none, so on the click event of a button or such the div with form appears

Comment: @alex...i think the html is adding in dom dynamically try event delegation see here    http://api.jquery.com/on/